# Help making auto updater

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, auto-update

I'm making a app that automatically updates itself. Fist of all I want to check if the file exists at a domain, I've never done something like it before so I've found a code and adapted it to fit in my project. The problem is that, I always get that the file exists.

```
-(BOOL) webFileExists {

int fcurVer = [[self getCurrentVersion] intValue];
fcurVer++;
NSLog(@"%i", fcurVer);
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.org/folder/version/%i.dmg", fcurVer];

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"statusCode = %i", [response statusCode]);

if ([response statusCode] == 404) {
    return NO;

}
else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

Any ideas? By the way if someone also knows how to download the file, and install it replacing the old one, please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has been solved by [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) already. It's widely used, well tested and trusted by users so why reinvent that wheel?

Also, it's open source and [hosted on github](https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle) so you can have a look at how it's implemented.